# how we can write node js server logs into a file if using node-windows

Tags: node.js, windows-services, node-windows

I am running by node js server as a windows service using a node module [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows)

I am able to start my server as a service but what if I want to see logs which my node server dumps in frequent intervals.

Answer (score 0):

node-windows is a wrapper, so what you're trying to do is only possible if you write the logging logic into your server.